# Construct custom directive: Directive.apply vs mapInnerRoute vs Directive.flatMap

Tags: scala, akka-http

I want to define custom directive using some built-in ones and my logic.
As I see all of `Directive.apply`, `BasicDirectives.mapInnerRoute` and `Directive.tflatMap` is suitable.

What is preferable in which cases and what best practices are?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the custom directives you wish to create it's impossible to discuss the suitability of the various options you listed.

The [documentation on this topic is fairly thorough](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/custom-directives.html):

> There are essentially three ways of creating custom directives:
>
> By introducing new “labels” for configurations of existing directives
>
> By transforming existing directives
>
> By writing a directive “from scratch”